# Not receiving correct pattern from regex on PyPDF2 for a PDF

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pdf, pypdf

I want to extract all instances of a particular word from a PDF e.g 'math'.
So far I am converting the PDF to Text using PyPDF2 and then doing regex on it to find what I want. This is the [example PFD](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dchzjrw9gpw6iil/TEST1.pdf?dl=0)

When I run my code instead of returning my regular expression pattern of 'math' It returns a string of the whole page. Please help Thanks

```
#First Change Current Working Directory to desktop

import os
os.chdir('/Users/Hussein/Desktop')         #File is located on Desktop


#Second is the PyPDF2

pdfFileObj=open('TEST1.pdf','rb')          #Opening the File
pdfReader=PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
pageObj=pdfReader.getPage(3)               #For the test I only need page 3
TextVersion=pageObj.extractText()
print(TextVersion)



#Third is the Regular Expression

import re
match=re.findall(r'math',TextVersion)
for match in TextVersion:
      print(match)
```

Instead of just getting all the instances of 'math' I receive this:

```
I
n
t
r
o
d
u
c
t
i
o
n
```

etc etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TextVersion` variable holds text. When you use it for a `for` loop, it will give you the text a character at a time as you have seen. The `findall` function will return a list of matches, so if you use this instead for your `for` loop you will get each word (which in your test will be all the same).

```
import re

for match in re.findall(r'math',TextVersion):
      print(match)
```

The returned result from `findall` would be something like:

```
["math", "math", "math"]
```

So your output will then be:

```
math
math
math
```

Answer (score 0):

You're actually iterating the value of `TextVersion` variable. You must iterate over the list returned by `re.findall`.

So your for loop must be,

```
match=re.findall(r'math',TextVersion)
for i in match:
    print(i)
```